Offset Lineart to display true silhouette?
Is there a setting or a way to offset line art silhouettes, so that it is only on the outside of an object? Like it is possible with the Outwards Solidify Method. Line art will be always displayed on the "edge" of an object, reaching slightly inwards, as outwards.
I already tried the offset-modifier, but the scaling options there are clearly not what I'm looking for.

Hello and welcome! Could you please provide some screenshots to clarify what you're trying to do? I'm having trouble understanding your goal, and visual examples would help a lot.
